# What is the usual/preferred landscape orientation for iOS apps?

Tags: ios, screen-orientation

Is it UIInterfaceLandscapeLeft (Home button on left) or UIInterfaceLandscapeRight (Home button on right)?

Note that the need is to support only one of them.

Comment: Why support only one of them? Surely you'll irritate some of your users?

Comment: I know, but it's a limitation with our code currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question!! Anyway...

As you can read [here](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development-advanced-discussion/40156-landscape-orientation-left-or-right-mostly-used.html), you should find something like this in the documentation.

> A landscape-only application should support both landscape
>   orientationsthat is, with the Home button on the right or on the
>   left. If the device is already physically in a landscape orientation,
>   a landscape-only application should launch in that orientation.
>   Otherwise, a landscape-only application should launch in the
>   orientation with the Home button on the right by default.

If so, `UIInterfaceLandscapeRight` should be prefered.

Comment: Haha. Thanks for answering this. I haven't done any iOS work since 2011, but glad to know that this is in the manual now. Back then, this excerpt didn't exist, IIRC.